# Make field required on certain condition only

Tags: python, mongodb, field, conditional-statements, mongoengine

I just started to use [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) these days and need to make a field required based on a certain condition.

My document structure looks like this (excerpt):

```
class Substance(Document):
    title                   =   StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    state                   =   StringField(choices=['solid', 'liquid', 'gaseous'], required=True)
    specific_gas_constant   =   FloatField(required=True)
```

As you can see, `specific_gas_constant` is set as a mandatory field.

From a physical point of view a [specific gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant#Specific_gas_constant) is only defined for `gaseous` substances, but not for `solid` or `liquid` ones. However, is there a way to make this field required based on the field `state`, since I did not find something like this in the [field docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#fields)?

Using [python-eve](http://python-eve.org/) before, I was able to enable a conditional requirement like this in the endpoints definition:

```
'specific_gas_constant': {
    'type': 'number',
    'dependencies': {'state': 'gaseous'},
},
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible with mongoengine but what I will do is give this field a default value and check the substance before saving or subclass the `Substance` class and set `required` to `True` for

Comment: How would I do a check before saving? Would I do this somehow manually or is there a way to overwrite `save()` in order to check the document class being `Substance`, check the `state` accordingly and raise something like a ValidationError if the substance is gaseous and has no gas constant specified?

Comment: You can overwrite save, in that case this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102103/using-mongoengine-document-class-methods-for-custom-validation-and-pre-save-hook) may be helpful.